# What programming languages are used in Shadowrun?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, tools, sr4-matrix

I'm looking for Shadowrun 4E fluff information on programming languages. What are the names of canon programming languages in 4E? C+++? SuperPython? etc? Please let me know where in what book you find it in.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: I can tell you that C+++ doesn't make much sense. "++" is an operator in C, which means 'increment after this operation', so C++ is a meaningful construct to a C programmer. However, I can also tell you that if I were playing a 'Runner, I'd be a SuperPython specialist in a hot tick!

Comment: I actually know C++; I was just making stuff up off the top of my head. =)

Comment: C+++ reminds me of a radio commercial for a job board website where they asked for c double plus programmers. I could not stop laughing.

Comment: C# already is C++++ (two pluses over two pluses to make the sharp sign)

Comment: Good point. So, I guess the next version would be C8va (an octave higher)? Not very catchy, though. Maybe it could be pronounced "Cava".

Comment: C8va... so Kate Virginia? Now there's an obscure pun for a SR hacker

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Page 81 of Matrix 3 (so sr3, not sr4) lists:

- HoloLISP
- InterMod
- MatComDev
- MCT Iconix 7
- Metacomm
- Novatech VRDrive 3
- Oblong
- Renraku Teng

Comment: What? No, "!BASIC" :)  My favorite future programming language btw...

Comment: @GMNoob: Where does not-BASIC come from?

Comment: I made it up :) I like the double (tirpple?) pun and the "full circle" view of the future.

Comment: While this list is complete. I am convinced that BF will stand the test of time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a programmer who's read most of the Shadowrun books and I can't recall ever seeing a specific language mentioned.